# How to center based on certain words in a line only?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes

I'm trying to center author information where some authors have asterisks after their names. The asterisks add width and thus shift the horizontal position of their lines. How can I center based on the names only, ignoring the asterisks?

```
% NOTE: The \ignoreForCenter command doesn't exist.
\begin{center}
  \textbf{First author\,\ignoreForCenter{\footnote{...}}}\\
  \textbf{Second author}\\
  \textbf{Third author}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the footnote using `\rlap` (or `\makebox[0pt][l]`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \textbf{First author\rlap{\,\footnotemark}}\footnotetext{This is a footnote.} \\
  \textbf{Second author} \\
  \textbf{Third author}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```